# How to return a private variable

Tags: java

Ok so I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to return a private variable from a class that I have created. I've only provided a small snippet of my main program to explain my question, so if more information is needed please let me know. My goal is to return a string from the class (working great), but also be able to return the private variables individually as needed (example used below is "flight_number").

```
public class Flights {
    private String dest_city, dest_state, departureDate, departureTime;
    private int flight_number;

    public Flights(String city, String state, String dDate, String dTime, int flightNumber) {
        dest_city = city;
        dest_state = state;
        departureDate = dDate;  
        departureTime = dTime;
        flight_number = flightNumber;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Flight number: " + flight_number + " Destination: " + dest_city + "," + dest_state + "  Departing  on:" + departureDate + " at" + departureTime + ".";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Uses the constructor to set values
        Flights flight1 = new Flights("Houston", "Texas", "12/20/2014", "12:40 pm", 100);
        System.out.println(flight1);
        System.out.println(flight_number); // Error: `flight_number` cannot be resolved to a variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that it is yet to early for you to write java code. Keep learning and stay closer to given example codes. Then try to work with working examples. Walk slowly.

Comment: `private` means... private. A class Dummy may not access a private field of another class Flights, by definition of `private`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Please format your code before posting it. You can preview how your question will look for a reason.

Comment: *Classes* do not return values. *Methods* return values. Add getter methods to your `Flights` class that return the value of one of the member variables, and then call these methods.

Comment: Yep, you should fix formating of yours snippets. If you really want to give acces to private field of your class use getter/setter methods. Also flight_number variable is not visible inside dummy class, and even if it was public you cannot use System.out.println(flight_number) (you should have prefixed it with flight1 e.g. flight1.flight_number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `public` *getter* in `Flights` and call it from `main`:

```
public class Flights {
    // all the private fields
    public int getFlightNumber() {
        return this.flight_number;
    }
}
```

In `Main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flights flight1 = new Flights("Houston", "Texas"); //...
    System.out.println(flight1);
    System.out.println(flight1.getFlightNumber());  // call the getter
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know this was a very remedial question, but I appreciate you taking the time to give me an example. This makes sense, I'll do more research on return statements and getter/setters.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with an editor like eclipse and that should help you get started quickly. Getters and Setters is what you need, but start with Eclipse and you should do better.